# Why are cases always entered in this PHP switch statement?

Tags: php, math

This is my code:

```
$array = [1,2,3];

foreach($array as $n){
  switch($n){
    case 1:
      print 1;
    case 2:
      print 2;
    default:
      print 3;
  }
}
```

It prints 123233

I don't get it, shouldn't it print 123 ?? I'm confused because:

- 1 is 1, but 2 is not 1, and 3 is not 1
- 2 is not 1, 2 is 2, 2 is not 3
- 3 is not 1, 3 is not 2, 3 is 3

Why isn't it working as expected?

Comment: You don't have breaks, your switch is falling through

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `break` after any print.

```
$array = [1,2,3];

foreach($array as $n){
  switch($n){
    case 1:
      print 1;
      break;
    case 2:
      print 2;
      break;
    default:
      print 3;
      break;
  }
}
```

If you wouldn't had a `break` keyword, then the code would be continue to be executed from the point of the case.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I guess he's practicing switch-case.

Comment: You should explain why adding a break is needed.